# Creating Maven ArcheType . Setting file name

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I want to create an Archetype in which the user can provide `artifactId`. Then I want to take this `artifactId` and create two files.

Here is an example.

```
artifactId= box

FILE 1: copy-box.txt
FILE 2 : Box.java
```

Creating `copy-box.txt` is quite easy. But how to create `Box.java` with `B` capital?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the code that creates the replacement in the filenames of the archetype resources (which can be found [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/archetype/trunk/archetype-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archetype/generator/DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java)). It seems that the values of the arguments are taken from the context, which means that they are not evaluated. In my opinion, for the moment it is not possible (sad, but true) to use the evaluation mechanism directly in the file names.

However, by simply implementing the `FilesetArchetypeGenerator` interface, a good contribution can be made to the archetypes generation.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in maven archetype. See bug reports [ARCHETYPE-406](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-406) and [ARCHETYPE-397](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-397).

When fixed it will be possible to define and use custom `requiredProperty` for your case.

In archetype-metadata.xml add

```
<requiredProperties>
  <requiredProperty key="classPrefix" >
    <defaultValue>
      ${artifactId.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()}${artifactId.substring(1)}
    </defaultValue>
  </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

Don't forget to add `classPrefix` to `archetype.properties`