# Camel case file name from artifactId for Maven archetype?

Tags: maven, velocity, minecraft, archetypes

For a Maven archetype, how to camel case a generated file name using `${artifactId}` in `archetype-metadata.xml`? For example, `sample-my` should give `SampleMy.java`.

I supposed this is needed to be a velocity template but this require a macro to be specified in `archetype-metadata.xml`. The macro could be created in **pluginApp**.java as shown at:

[https://github.com/arun-gupta/spigot-archetype/blob/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/**pluginApp**.java#L4-L7](https://github.com/arun-gupta/spigot-archetype/blob/master/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/__pluginApp__.java#L4-L7)

How can it be done `archetype-metadata.xml`?

Exact fragment in question is at:

https://github.com/arun-gupta/spigot-archetype/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml#L14

Comment: I also searched for a solution an find it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773114/creating-maven-archetype-setting-file-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Maven ArcheType . Setting file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773114/creating-maven-archetype-setting-file-name)

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it as follows:

```
    <requiredProperty key="classPrefix" >
        <defaultValue>
            ${package.getClass().forName("org.apache.velocity.util.StringUtils").removeAndHump("$artifactId", "-")}
        </defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
```

Comment: shouldnt there be curly braces aroudn the $artifactID